# Azure subscription credits ended but need to view the ADF pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-resource-manager, cost-management, azure-subscription

I had been using Azure subscription with free credits and the credits have finished. I wanted to look into the pipelines I had created in ADF to replicate in some other subscription.

Is there any way I can do that without paying for the cost.

Comment: Are you sure you can’t even view your pipeline?  You cannot run it but you should be able to view it.  Also, did you connect it to source code control repository?  If so, you will be able to view the raw json there.

Comment: I didn't connect it to the git repo and yes the adf is just loading and nothing happening thereafter.

Comment: You can still look at its settings though, its json?  That’s the definition of the pipeline and would allow you to replicate it elsewhere.

Comment: yes I can recreate using that. thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to view the JSON of your activity from Resource group> Activity Log > JSON but To continue using Azure services, As of now, there is no way you can do it without paying the cost. However, you can choose pay as you go, but before you can get estimated costs before adding Azure services from [Pricing calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/) or you can request a quote related to Azure Data Factory Pipeline from [Data Pipeline pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/data-factory/data-pipeline/).

> Once your free services and quantities expire, you're charged pay-as-you-go rates for any services you're using.

[image]

**REFERENCES:** [You reached the end of your free 12 months](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/avoid-charges-free-account#you-reached-the-end-of-your-free-12-months)